# Posts in Admin only display 1 Post instead of all Post in admin area

Tags: plugins, php

> Hi everyone, I am using M.E calendar plugin and i have published more event but in admin section showing only 1 post in all event area. As you can see screenshot below
> [image]

Comment: You should inquire with the plugin developer.  It's rare that anyone is able to help with just a screen capture of a third party plugin's interface.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.